# How to generate a single storybook for storybook 5

Tags: storybook

The main `build-storybook` does not seem to accept a single storybook argument.

```
build-storybook --help
Usage: build-storybook [options]
    Options:
      -V, --version                 output the version number
      -s, --static-dir <dir-names>  Directory where to load static files from
      -o, --output-dir [dir-name]   Directory where to store built files
      -c, --config-dir [dir-name]   Directory where to load Storybook configurations from
      -w, --watch                   Enable watch mode
      -h, --help                    output usage information
```

Is it possible to make `build-storybook` only build one storybook specifically?

Comment: I'm not aware of a built-in method that does that. A workaround would be to write a script that accepts a path to the storybook you want to build. This then generates a Storybook-configuration that you can reference with the `-c` flag

Comment: I'm don't understand what sort of option you're looking for.

What do you mean by "build one storybook", what's the desired output like?